# Координаты в двумерном массиве

Tags: java

Создаем произвольный прямоугольник N x M. Создаем одномерный массив с 4 элементами в котором каждый чётный элемент содержит координату области по первому измерению N, а каждый нечётный элемент содержит координату области по второму измерению M. Как задать эти две координаты через двумерный массив? Должно получиться как на картинке.

[image: Должно получиться как на картинке]

Одномерный массив с 4 элементами имеет индекс (0 - (четный индекс координаты по массиву N), 1 - (нечетный индекс координаты по массиву M), 2 - (четyый индекс координаты по массиву N), 3 - (нечетный индекс координаты по массиву M)) 0-ой индекс = 2, 1-ый индекс = 2, 2-ой индекс = 3, 3-ий индекс = 4. Первые координаты из массива battalion x = 2, y = 2 Вторые координаты из массива battalion x = 3, y = 4

```
public class Proba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 3;//ширина территории
        int M = 4;//длина территории
        int[] battalion = {2, 2, 3, 4};
        int[][] stateOfSquares = new int[3][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Можно задать так: `stateOfSquares[batallion[0], batallion[1]] = 1; stateOfSquares[batallion[2], batallion[3]] = 1;` В каком-то пространстве смыслов это может оказать подходящим способом :). А вообще-то я тоже ничего не понял. Что вы понимаете под "задать эти две координаты в двумерном массиве"?

Comment: @Igor@Pavel Исправил условие. Так понятнее?

Comment: @Алексей Андреев Одномерный массив содержит две координаты по (x и y), двумерный массив создает поле где должны быть размещены эти координаты.

Comment: @FDmitriyA Вроде понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Proba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 3;//ширина территории
        int M = 4;//длина территории
        int[] battalion = {2, 2, 3, 4};
        int[][] stateOfSquares = new int[3][4];
        // assume length of battalion is even
        for (int i = 0; i < battalion.length; i = i + 2) {
            stateOfSquares[battalion[i] - 1][battalion[i + 1] - 1] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Все получилось. Можно с вами связаться через телеграмм, у этой задачи есть продолжение.

Comment: @FDmitriyA К сожалению, я не пользуюсь телеграмм. Но Вы можете задать еще один вопрос на ruSO. Я его, вероятно, увижу.

Comment: Продолжение задачки)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1095963/371025

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно идти двумя циклами по двумерному. Идите одним циклом по одномерному,  идите с шагом в два. И эти значения используйте как индексы двумерного

Comment: Либо Вы не в ту сторону повернули, либо же я смотрю на ваш совет по реализации двумерной вселенной совсем с другого угла. Можете пример кода добавить? А то мозг немного кипит при попытке это в голове представить.

Comment: Игор написал код совпадающие с моими словами 1 в 1

Comment: @АлексейАндреев Код совпадает с вашим советом, но я не понял ваш совет, извините, я только начинаю программировать. Проще понять совет если в нем указан конкретный код, еще лучше если код сопровождается комментариями. Спасибо за участие!